# Dynamically loading the javascript files

Tags: extjs

I am trying to add Nivo chart to my ExtJS based application. If I generate the build for Nivo chart then it creates multiple files. I need to load them dynamically in my ExtJS application. What is a best way to do that?

Also, Nivo chart build generates one index.html file which has references of all the javascript files. So is there a way to load all these script files in ExtJS using the index.html?

Comment: Check out Ext.Loader.loadScript method. In case you wanna load many files, i would suggest to promisify it. For further requests, please share code what you did and trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Synchronous : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.Loader.html#method-loadScript

```
    Ext.Loader.loadScriptsSync(url);
```

2. Asynchronous : https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.Loader.html#method-loadScript

```
    Ext.Loader.loadScript({
        url: scriptUrl,
        onLoad: fn
    });
```